# iOS Mobile Safari File Upload renames file

Tags: ios, file-upload, mobile-safari

I have a web app designed for use on an iOS device.  The web app includes file uploaders, which are meant to allow the user to upload an image from their iOS device or take an image from their camera.

The issue I'm running into is that I want the user to be able to upload PNG images through this interface, as well.

What is happening, though, is that it seems iOS renames the file `image.jpg` before it is sent to the web app, not honoring the original file extension.  This is only an issue because I am trying to preserve transparency in the .png files, and this is lost in the extension renaming.

Any thoughts on how to handle this?  Thanks, in advance, for any assistance on this front.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile Safari only allows the uploads of jpeg's at this time. If you try to upload a png it will be (heavily) compressed into the jpeg format and then uploaded to the server.

The only way we have been about to get around this is by creating a native app for iOS and uploading the image through the Cocoa-Touch API's.

I've filed a Bug report with apple for this issue. Bug ID: 14494395

Comment: Not sure this is related to only .png, I have the same issues with upload .jpg through web on iOS, safari and Chrome.

Comment: We have an app that was running under iOS 8.0 which uploads extension of **jpg**.  Now under iOS 9.0 the extension has chaged to **jpeg**. @joel-dell, do you know if Apple addressed your bug?

Comment: They never directly addressed my bug report except by saying this was expected behavior. I honestly haven't tried in the past year or two so i'm not sure whats changed with iOS 8 - 9.